# If $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n = \frac{a+b}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n = \frac{a+b}{2}$. Can you help me? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique is standard:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n)=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{(n+a)(n+b)-n^2}{\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}+n}
$$
Then expand the numerator and divide numerator and denominator by $n$.

By the way, the relation holds for any $a$ and $b$, provided you consider the sequence defined for $n>\max(-a,-b)$.

Comment: +1 though I personally would add an extra step showing that $n^2$ is cancelled in the numerator.

Comment: @yurnero Well, this is just a hint, isn't it? However I added a word.

Comment: That is definitely nitpicking, but starting with $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$ and carrying it throughout *presupposes* the existence of the limit — which is not immediately obvious (or wouldn't be if the OP didn't basically do the same).

Comment: @ClementC. When computing limits, equalities are “conditional”. One carries on and, if the limit is eventually found, everything is good; otherwise one has to go back and try a different path (or prove the limit doesn't exist). Since *this* path succeeds… You'd have to make the same comment in thousands of threads on this site. ;-)

Comment: ... everything is fine. My only worry is that the notation being conditional may not be clear to new students, for instance: "if we write the limit, then it must exist, right?" (But yes, I won't go on a crusade I will lose by exhaustion.)

Comment: @ClementC. I trust instructors tell this to their students. Otherwise notation would be very cumbersome. In this case, however, the limit on the left hand side exists *if and only if* the limit on the right hand side exists (it's just a rewriting of the function).

Comment: (anyway, let me know if you'd rather I delete my comments.)

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \sqrt { (n+a)(n+b) } -n=\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { \left( \sqrt { (n+a)(n+b) } -n \right) \left( \sqrt { (n+a)(n+b) } +n \right)  }{ \sqrt { (n+a)(n+b) } +n } =\\ =\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { (n+a)(n+b)-{ n }^{ 2 } }{ n\left( \sqrt { \left( 1+\frac { a }{ n }  \right) \left( 1+\frac { b }{ n }  \right)  } +1 \right)  } =\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { n\left( a+b+\frac { ab }{ n }  \right)  }{ n\left( \sqrt { \left( 1+\frac { a }{ n }  \right) \left( 1+\frac { b }{ n }  \right)  } +1 \right)  } =\frac { a+b }{ 2 } $$

Comment: it should be n ,thank you

Answer (score 1):

To complement [egreg's excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820177/75808), here is another proof, based (for the sake of diversity) on Taylor expansions:
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}
&= \sqrt{n^2 + (a+b)n + ab}
= \sqrt{n^2}\sqrt{1 + \frac{a+b}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\\
&\stackrel{(\dagger)}{=} n\left( 1 + \frac{a+b}{2n} +o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)
= n + \frac{a+b}{2} +o\left(1\right)
\end{align}$$
so that
$$
\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)} - n = \frac{a+b}{2} +o\left(1\right) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}
\frac{a+b}{2}. 
$$

---

$(\dagger)$ We used the Taylor expansion (to second order) at $0$ of $\sqrt{1+u}$, namely 
$$\sqrt{1+u} = 1+\frac{u}{2} + o(u).$$
*(This in turn, in this case, is equivalent to knowing the derivative at $0$ of $u\mapsto \sqrt{1+u}$.)*